# save nested attributes in textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models Deal and Coupon.

Deal

```
has_many :couponizations, dependent: :destroy
has_many :coupons, through: :couponizations, source: :coupon
accepts_nested_attributes for :coupons
```

So each deal  has many coupon codes, which are saved in separate table and associated via couponizations table. What I want to do is to save coupon codes attributes for deal via textarea field in Deal form (each coupon code on new line)

Form looks like this:

---

**Deal title:**  || New Deal Title ||

---

**Coupon codes:**

- | TESTCOUPON1 |
- | TESTCOUPON2 |
- | TESTCOUPON3 |

---

I realize that probably I need to create virtual attribute  "coupon_codes" and then split it by "\n" and save it in controller. Is there any best-practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging 
There's a good solution for array of object with nested elements like tags.
Just split the text by "\n"

Comment: for some reason I needed to use "\r\n"